# Testing some complex String on the standard output with JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

What is the best way to test some complex String on the standard output with JUnit ?

I'm making some test for a programme in Java with JUnit. I want to test some method that display complex String in the Standard output.

For example I have a method that displays :

```
Index   Marque  Modèle  Pays    Vente   
1       Renault Clio    France  12000   
2       Peugeot 208     France  9900
```

So there are some `\t` and `\n`, some spaces and a lot of text. I've made this test (that works) but it doesn't seem like a good practice :

```
String s = System.getProperty("line.separator");    
assertEquals("Index\tMarque\tModèle\tPays\tVente\t"+s+"1\tRenault\tClio\tFrance\t12000\t"+s+"2\tPeugeot\t208\tFrance\t9900\t"+s, outContent.toString());
```

It seems awful and laborious, it works but maybe there are some better ways.

Comment: Regex is your friend :), a slow but robust one.

Comment: You could use Kotlin which has multi-line string literals. Or you could read the expected output from a resource. Or you could instead of writing to the output generate a data structure (a List<Car>) and check that the returned list is correct. You would then have a single method to write a List<Car> to the output, that you need to test only once.

Answer (score 0):

Wehen we write unittests each test method should verify a *single expectation* on the thested unit only.

In my view your complex output has multiple  of such *singe expectations*:

1. the output contains a header line
2. the "fields" of the header line are separated with (at least) on `\t` char
3. each line ends with the systems line separator
4. each product adds a separate line
5. all product lines start with a consecutive number in the first field
6. ...

This may look like a lot of work to create all that test methods but consider this:

- The names of the test methods describe exactly what the unit does
- when you change your logic (accidentally) you get a very accurate description how the unit fails the already defined behavior without debugging, just by looking at the test results.